# Drupal 7 WSOD and PHP Fatal Error

Tags: drupal-7, fatal-error, wsod

Thanks in advanced for looking at my post!  I developed this Commerce Kickstart site locally using Aquia Dev Desktop and everything looked and functioned great.  When I post it to the server, I get the WSOD, and an error in the error_log:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  delta_get_current() in /xxx/xxx/xxx/profiles/commerce_kickstart/themes/omega/alpha/includes/alpha.inc on line 222

This is a site that had been working fine remotely also, except for an issue with the checkout. (the original reason for taking it down.) I had to refer to a backup copy of the site, make some changes to get it to be more recent and then post it. That's when I received the WSOD and Php Fatal Errors.

If you have any advice on how to fix or where to proceed, please let me know. Also, let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks again.
Jason

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you're working with the right module and theme versions.  See what you can do to update Delta to fix it, also update Omega.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  The main Commerce Kickstart distribution was needing an update.  So, I did that.  Do you think that could be it?  I'll try to upload again and see if that made a difference.

Comment: I updated the Commerce Kickstart distribution, and that didn't help.  Still getting WSOD.  This is the error:   PHP Warning:  include_once(/xxx/xxx/xxx/includes/bootstrap.inc) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xmlrpc.php on line 13.   What should I do?

Comment: Your Drupal root is messed up.  Maybe changes were made to the .php files that shouldn't have been, or possibly a change happened in your .htaccess, or something to that tune.  I don't know what the redacted directory structure is, so I can't help there, but basically you'll need to properly configure your DRUPAL_ROOT, and it's easiest to do it via .htaccess.